# Access Custom Admin Page on AppEngine Development Server

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using Appengine and I want to write a custom admin page for myself. How can I view the custom admin page on the development server (on my localhost)?

The localhost console does not seem to have a link to it (even though it's defined in the .yaml and the page is working properly).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the URL in your browser, i.e.

```
 http://localhost:8080/MyAdminPage.html
```